# How to select even or odd elements based on class name

Tags: javascript, mootools

if you create html layout like so

```
<ul>
     <li class='a'></li>
     <li class='b'></li>
     <li class='a'></li>
     <li class='b'></li>
     <li class='a'></li>
     <li class='b'></li>
     <li class='a'></li>
     <li class='b'></li>
</ul>
```

and try to select odd elements with 'a' class like so $$('.a:odd') you will get empty array, and if you do $$('.a:even') you will get all four li elements with 'a' class.. It really strange.. But im new to mootools, maybe im doing something wrong..

So my question is how to select first and third li elements with a class.
I know that i can do it with function like this

$$('.a').filter(function(item, index) { return index%2; }

but its too complicated for such small task as selecting odd or even elements..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that :odd and :even (and their CSS cousins :nth-child(odd) and :nth-child(even)) refer to the order in which the elements appear as children of their parent, not as children with that particular selector.

This worked for me (Prototype, but it looks like MooTools has similar syntax):

```
var odd = $$('.a').filter(function(item, index) {
    return index % 2 == 0;
});
var even = $$('.a').filter(function(item, index) {
    return index % 2 == 1;
});
```

Edit: it seems you already covered that in the question, boo on me for answering before reading fully.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the 1st and third, you just need $$('.a').

Are you trying to get the 1st and 5th items? That would be something like $$('a:nth-child(4n+1))

I am assuming mootools uses [css3 Structural pseudo-classes](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

The :nth-child pseudo selector looks at the DOM element's [(non-zero indexed) index](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#structural-pseudos), not within the selected (matching) elements. MooTools added the [':odd'](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Utilities/Selectors#Selector:odd) selector to select 'real' odd elements, therefore the index starts at 0.

So in your example, selecting '.a:nth-child(odd)' will return all li.a elements, because the index starts at 1. Selecting '.a:odd' selects nothing, because there are no 'real' odd li.a elements.

What you probably want, is to select the [':nth-of-type'](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-of-type-pseudo) element. So selecting '.a:nth-of-type(odd)' would return all odd li.a elements (the first and third one - it uses the DOM element's index).

MooTools does not support the ':nth-of-type' selector by default, but you can extend the selector engine using the Selectors.Pseudo class (can't find an example right now).

Answer (score -1):

**eyelidlessness**, so you say it's not a bug? It the way it should work?

Comment: Yes. It is correct according to spec (assuming :even and :odd to be shorthand for their CSS :nth-child(*) cousins)